# <div> not showing after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to build a Webapp using FLask and using simple HTML and CSS for the frontend as I am new to this. Now the problem I am facing is that the `<div class="blocking">` is not showing after I submit the form but the  `<div class="spinner">` is working fine. Below is the code

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
 
 <body>

  <form role="form" action="/reviewrequest/{{ value }}" method="POST" onSubmit="return validateForm():">

     <table> ............. </table>

     <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success success" />
     <div id="blocking" class="blocking">
     <div id="spinner" class"center loading"></div></div>
  </form>

<script>
 function validateForm(){
     document.getElementById("blocking").style.display =  = 'block';
     document.getElementById("spinner").style.display =  = 'block';
 }
</script>

</body>
{% endblock %}
```

NOTE: The same CSS code working on another HTML file.

EDIT: Added '.style.display' but still its same only the spinner is showing

```css
<style type="text/css">

    #spinner {
        display: none;
    }

    .loading {
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-top-color: #1ecd97;
        border-left-color: #1ecd97;
        animation: spin 1s infinite ease-in;
    }

    @keyframes spin {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

  #blocking {
         display: none;
   }
  
  .blocking{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75) no repeat center center;
  }
 
</style>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("blocking") = 'block';` just makes zero sense. That is not how setting inline styles works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style#setting_styles

Comment: I know it might make no sense as this is the 2day I have ever written any JS code

Comment: that is there I missed that part, I wrote the code here as my actual code is in a restricted env

Comment: You have two `==` there, which does nothing. It's now an expression and amounts to `false;`. Use a single `=` to assign the value on the right to the variable on the left. There's also a `=` missing in your spinner HTML when you set the `class` attribute. You also have `onSubmit="return validateForm():"` but it's supposed to be a semi-colon `;` not a colon. You also shouldn't use inline code like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `document.getElementById("blocking").style.display = "block";` to set the display property of the specified Element.

Comment: [Please do not use, recommend or link to w3schools.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Comment: Could you add the css for the used classes? This might help locating the problem

Comment: Hi, added the css part, thanks for your response

Comment: What is the blocking element supposed to do? I recreated the your code and in my opinion it works quite fine.
The 'blocking' element in your example is surrounding the spinner, that means you only can see the spinner element when the blocking element is visible, too.

I would recommend to take a look into the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) to see how the styles get added.

Comment: Actually, I want the whole page to be disabled and the spinner will show the "blocking" part is to restrict the users from clicking anything once they submit the form.

Comment: In this case, you might want to wrap the 'blocking'-div around the form, but I don't think that would get you the intended result either. 
You might instead want to disable the submit-button by calling `document.getElementById("submitBtn").disabled = true; `.
You have to add 'id="submitBtn"' to the button for this to work.